# Signal R responding with error 401 when trying to connect

Tags: asp.net, signalr, windows-server

our application is migrated from Windows server 2012 to windows server 2019 standard. Both our app server and IIS server have been migrated.

We are using Signal R version 2.2.0 in our application. When I am trying to fetch data with signal R URL I am getting unauthorized error 401.

I did debug and found that it is failing with message "Error: Error during negotiation request."  when we are calling `connection.start()`

**Stack Trace:** (I replaced server details with server name for security purpose)

```
at Object.error (https://serverName/scripts/vendor.js?v=1.11.10820:72734:25)
at g (https://serverName/scripts/vendor.js?v=1.11.10820:72879:41)
at Object.error (https://serverName/scripts/vendor.js?v=1.11.10820:72886:47)
at i (https://serverName/scripts/vendor.js?v=1.11.10820:1410:30)
at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (https://serverName/scripts/vendor.js?v=1.11.10820:1455:101)
at z (https://serverName/scripts/vendor.js?v=1.11.10820:3691:619)
at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (https://serverName/scripts/vendor.js?v=1.11.10820:3865:229)
```

I installed websocket Protocols as per this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30355960/signalr-error-during-negotiation-request) in both my app server and IIS server, restarted the servers and also services.

I observed the difference in ASP.Net versions.

- Windows server 2012 - ASP.Net 4.5
- Windows server 2019 - ASP.Net 4.7

Is it required only Asp.Net 4.5?